# Get date from day of week, year, and week number

Tags: php

I have:

- a week number
- a day of week
- a year

I want to find the date from that. How to do it in PHP?

**Example:**

```
$day = "wednesday";
$week = 1;
$year = 2019
getDate($day, $week, $year) // must return 2019-01-02
```

Comment: Can you attach your data to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below one

```
$day = array(
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
);
$intday = array_search('Saturday', $day);
$gendate = new DateTime();
$gendate->setISODate(2019,1,$intday); //Year, week number, day
echo $gendate->format('d-m-Y');
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you I was looking for setISODate() wich I just discover the existance !

Answer (score 2):

Use [setISODate()](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.setisodate.php)

```
$year = 2018;
$weakNum = 50;
$dayNum = 3;
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate($year,$weakNum,$dayNum); 
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<?php
$gendate = new DateTime();
$gendate->setISODate(2019,1,3); //year , week num , day
echo $gendate->format('Y-m-d'); //"prints"  2019-01-02
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
$weekNo = date("W", strtotime("2018-12-20"));
```